# Ansible send file to the first met destination

Tags: copy, ansible, nagios, nrpe

I'm sending a config file for thousands of nodes,  because of some customisation there's maybe 5 or 6 paths to that file (There's only one file for host but the path can vary) and there isn't a easy way to figure out the default location with facts.

Based on this, I'm looking for some way to set the "dest" of copy module like we can set the "src", with a [`with_first_found` loop](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#finding-first-matched-files).

Something like that:

```
copy: src=/foo/{{ ansible_hostname }}/nrpe.cfg dest="{{item}}
with_items:
    - "/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib64/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/opt/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
```

PS: I'm sending nrpe.cfg so if someone knows a better way to find where's the default nrpe.cfg it will be a lot easier.

**EDIT 1**: I've managed to work with the help from @ydaetskcoR like this:

```
- name: find nrpe.cfg
  stat:
    path: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib64/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/opt/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
  register: nrpe_stat
  no_log: True

- name: Copy nrpe.cfg
  copy: src=/foo/{{ ansible_hostname }}/nrpe.cfg dest="{{item.stat.path}}"
  when: item.stat.exists
  no_log: True
  with_items:
    - "{{nrpe_stat.results}}"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option could be to simply search for the already existing `nrpe.cfg` file and then register that location as a variable to be used for the copy task.

You could do that either through a shell/command task that just uses `find` or loop through a bunch of locations with [`stat`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/stat_module.html) to check if they exist.

So you might have something like this:

```
- name: find nrpe.cfg
  shell: find / -name nrpe.cfg
  register: nrpe_path

- name: overwrite nrpe.cfg
  copy: src=/foo/{{ ansible_hostname }}/nrpe.cfg dest="{{item}}"
  with_items:
    - nrpe_path.stdout_lines
  when: nrpe_path.stdout != ""
  register: nrpe_copied

- name: copy nrpe.cfg to box if not already there
  copy: src=/foo/{{ ansible_hostname }}/nrpe.cfg dest="{{ default_nrpe_path }}"
  when: nrpe_copied is not defined
```

As [Mxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/949859/mxx) pointed out in the comments, we have a third task to fall back to copying to some default path (potentially `/etc/nagios/` or any other path really) if the `nrpe.cfg` file hasn't been found by `find`.

To use `stat` rather than a shell/command task you could do something like this:

```
- name: find nrpe.cfg
  stat: 
    path: {{ item }}
  with_items:
    - "/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/local/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib64/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/usr/lib/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
    - "/opt/nagios/etc/nrpe.cfg"
  register: nrpe_stat

- name: overwrite nrpe.cfg
  copy: src=/foo/{{ ansible_hostname }}/nrpe.cfg dest="{{item.stat.path}}"
  when: item.stat.exists
  with_items:
    - "{{nrpe_stat.results}}"
```

Comment: Hello @ydaetskcoR, this is actually what I'm doing right now but I'm trying to find a solution without shell so I could use --check

Comment: I've added a first stab at what you might need for using stat instead but don't have the time to test it and then tweak it to get it working. If you can work it out yourself then feel free to suggest an edit otherwise I'll try and have another look at this when I've got some free time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited my post to share my last effort. The problem now it's --diff doesn't work anymore

Comment: Don't know why, but it's working now. Thanks for your help again

Comment: I meant suggest an edit to the answer. I've added it in myself though. Thanks for finishing it off.

Comment: But this won't copy the file if it's completely missing from the destination server..

Comment: Good point. I've updated the original example to register a variable when overwriting nrpe.cfg and then a fall back task that puts nrpe.cfg in a default path if it hasn't already copied nrpe.cfg across. Need to update second part as well when I get a chance.