# Ansible: get files list from local directory

Tags: ansible

I use ansible 1.9.4 and I would like to get the list of files from a local directory.

In 2.0 version, there is the [find module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html) but this version is beta.

How to do this in < 2.0 ?

Comment: Actually Ansible 2 is no longer beta, it has been released two days ago. http://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-2.0-launch

Comment: Great. I'll try this

Comment: It is possible in 1.9.4. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to list a directory to send each file on remote host AND do a specific manipulation with it

Answer (score 20):

Some time ago I was building an automation that required something like that - see [Ansible send file to the first met destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34344321/ansible-send-file-to-the-first-met-destination).

Prior to ansible 2.0 there's no way to do this without using  `command` or `shell`.

If you really can't upgrade to ansible 2.0, use the `command` module:

```
vars:
  directory: /path/to/dir

tasks:

  - command: "ls {{directory}}"
    register: dir_out

  - debug: var={{item}}
    with_items: dir_out.stdout_lines
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought about this module but I find this ugly. But if it's the only one solution, let's go.

Comment: since I wanted a playbook to get file list from local/ansible host and do tasks against remote hosts I needed delegate_to: localhost ... as per @user43731 example

Answer (score 14):

This is an example of listing all the files with .j2 extension in the directory templates and passing them to a module.

```
template: src="{{ item }}" dest="generated/{{ inventory_hostname }}/{{ item | basename | replace('.j2', '')}}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  with_fileglob: templates/*.j2
```

Answer (score 14):

Now there is a find module you can use.
Example: show folders with name starting with "ansible" and location /tmp, so /tmp/ansible*

```
- name: ls -d /tmp/ansible*
  find:
    paths: /tmp
    patterns: "ansible*"
    recurse: no
    file_type: directory
  register: found_directories

- debug:
    msg: "{{ [item.path] }} "
  with_items: "{{ found_directories.files }}"
```

Comment: From the testing that I've done, `find` works on the remote, not against local.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I have it working on local, the host and connection an ansible module is used on should not affect it. You may be missing something in your setup.